# Google Form Regular Expression - Limit Input to 3-digits and 1 case-insensitive alphabet

Tags: google-forms

I am trying to limit the input on a Google Form to 3 digits and 1 case-insensitive alphabet, e.g. 123A or 123a. Tried \d{3}[[:alpha:]] but doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`[[:alpha:]]` is not supported, instead you should use `\d{3}[a-zA-Z]`.

Reference:

[Examples of regular expressions](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3378864?hl=en#zippy=%2Cexamples-of-regular-expressions)